# uitoolbar in navigation bar.

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

this is a simple problem, but i'm new to xcode dev. I followed a guide online to have multiple buttons on a navigation bar. the edit button on the navgivation bar has a `IBAction` method called "editButton". which has a `(id)sender` as parameter. do I get the sender and change the text from edit to done, done to edit?

`"UIBarButtonitem *bbi = (UIBarButonItem *) sender;"` doesn't seem to be working. how do i get the button in the toolbar in navigationbar?

Thank you.

```
UIToolbar* tools = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 133, 44.01)];

// create the array to hold the buttons, which then gets added to the toolbar
NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

// create a standard "add" button
UIBarButtonItem* bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:NULL];
bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

// create a spacer
bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

// create a standard "EDIT" button
bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editButton:)];
bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

// stick the buttons in the toolbar
[tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];

[buttons release];

// and put the toolbar in the nav bar
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
[tools release];



-(IBAction)editButton:(id) sender{
UIBarButtonitem *bbi = (UIBarButonItem *) sender;

if (bbi title isequalsString:@"Done){
[bbi setTitle:@"Edit"];
}
}else{
[bbi setTitle:@"Done"];
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that you have used a *UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit*, not a standard uibarbutton.
Try creating it with:

```
bi = [UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered  target:self action:@selector(editButton:)];
```

Then use the rest of the code as is.

Comment: exactly the way you do it now - by casting it from sender: UIBarButtonitem *bbi = (UIBarButonItem *) sender;

Answer (score 0):

UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit is a special bar button item that takes care of the "Edit / Done" states for you. No need to manually change the button's text.

Comment: I actually misspoke. If you are using a UIViewController subclass, you should be able to use the built-in edit button property.

`[self editButtonItem]`